# can I use compromise in this way?

Tags: meaning

can I use compromise or build in this context?

> The android application elements and the the service provider elements compromise the bus traffic monitoring system

Comment: I guess that you mean "comprise" rather than "compromise".

Comment: Yeah, words can often be mixed up, even by natives, due to them having the same beginning and ending sounds.

Answer (score 1):

The correct word is "comprise".

"compromise" has meanings described on this page:

[Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compromise)

"comprise", meanwhile:

["comprise"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comprise)